# How to use MouseListener event

Tags: java, mouselistener

I have a  main class implements MouseListener and a TimerTask inside this class. How can I run this code inside MouseEnter event. I mean when mouse over the frame Timer task will execute specified times

```
public class NewClass extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

 public NewClass() {
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    addMouseListener(this);
    Timer t=new Timer();
    TimerTask task=new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
             System.out.println("heloo");
        }
    };
   t.schedule(task, 1000);

   }


@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {

}


public static  void main(String[]args){

    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    frame.add(new NewClass());
    frame.setSize(300,300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you want the timer to fire as long as the mouse is in your panel? Or should the timer reset as long as you keep on moving?

Comment: Just when MouseEnter event works run method will also work in every 1000ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use **[Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html)** for GUI related tasks, as in javadoc mentioned:

> In general, we recommend using Swing timers rather than
>   general-purpose timers for GUI-related tasks because Swing timers all
>   share the same, pre-existing timer thread and the GUI-related task
>   automatically executes on the event-dispatch thread. However, you
>   might use a general-purpose timer if you don't plan on touching the
>   GUI from the timer, or need to perform lengthy processing.

After reading the tutorial you will understand what I did:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class TimerDemo extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private javax.swing.Timer timer;

    public TimerDemo() {
        super("Panel Timer Demo");
        //initialing swing timer
        timer = new javax.swing.Timer(100, getButtonAction());
        JPanel p = new JPanel ();
        p.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent ev){
                timer.start();
            }
            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent ev){
                timer.stop();
                }
            });

          p.setBackground(Color.blue);

          getContentPane().add(p,BorderLayout.CENTER);
          setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
          setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          pack();
    }

    private ActionListener getButtonAction() {
        ActionListener action = new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Heloo");
            }
        };
        return action;
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TimerDemo().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: this is way more complicated than it needs to be. Just use `SwingUtilities#invokeLater(Runnable)` or `SwingUtilities#invokeAndWait(Runnable)` for updating the UI.